# How do I Dynamically create a Test Suite in JUnit 4?

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I would like to create a junit test suite using JUnit 4 where the names of the test classes to be included are not known until the test suite is run.

In JUnit 3 I could do this:

```
public final class MasterTester extends TestCase
{
  /**
   * Used by junit to specify what TestCases to run.
   * 
   * @return a suite containing what TestCases to run
   */
  public static TestSuite suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

    for(Class<?> klass : gatherTestClasses()) {
      suite.addTestSuite(klass);
    }

    return suite;
  }
}
```

and let the `gatherTestClasses()` method deal with figuring out what test classes to run.

In JUnit 4, the [documentation](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/) says to use an annotation: `@SuiteClasses({TestClass1.class, TestClass2.class...})` to build up my test suite.  There are [numerous SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190224/junit-and-junit-framework-testsuite-no-runnable-methods/190347#190347) showing how to do this.  Unfortunately the examples I see do not seem to allow for passing a dynamically generated list of TestClasses.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645154/how-do-i-define-a-testsuite-without-using-suiteclasses-in-junit-4-5) suggested I would have to subclass `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` which I do not want to do.

Dynamically specified test suites seem like something that must be in JUnit 4 somewhere.  Does anyone know where?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I found Classpath suite quite useful when used with a naming convention on my test classes.

https://github.com/takari/takari-cpsuite

Here is an example:

```
import org.junit.extensions.cpsuite.ClasspathSuite;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@ClassnameFilters({".*UnitTest"})
public class MySuite {
}
```

Comment: Andrejs's answer makes Classpath redundant, at least for the task of creating test suites dynamically.

Comment: Looks like it isn't maintained anymore, and has lot of troubles with native libraries and such

Answer (score 41):

To create a dynamic test suite, you need to use the `@RunWith` annotation. There are two common ways to use it:

**`@RunWith(Suite.class)`**

This allows you to specify, which classes compose the test suite in question. This is equivalent to the JUnit 3 style:

```
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public final class MasterTester extends TestCase {

  public static TestSuite suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
    suite.addTestSuite(TestClass1.class);        
    suite.addTestSuite(TestClass2.class);
    // etc...
    return suite;
  }
}
```

The equivalent JUnit 4 class will be:

```
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({TestClass1.class, TestClass2.class})
public final class MasterTester {

}
```

**`@RunWith(AllTests.class)`**

This allows you to dynamically specify the tests, which compose the test suite. If your tests are not known until runtime, you cannot specify them in the annotations. You can use this construction instead. So, if the JUnit 3 code is:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import junit.framework.Test;

public final class MasterTester extends TestCase {

  public static TestSuite suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
    for (Test test : findAllTestCasesRuntime()) {
      suite.addTest(test);
    }
    return suite;
  }
}
```

The equivalent JUnit 4 code will be:

```
import org.junit.runners.AllTests;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import junit.framework.Test;

@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public final class MasterTester {

  public static TestSuite suite() {
    TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
    for (Test test : findAllTestCasesRuntime()) {
      suite.addTest(test);
    }
    return suite;
  }
}
```

Comment: The action inside this for loop seems wrong. Do you mean to do suite.addTest(test); ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I've updated the sources to use addTest() and addTestSuite()

Comment: why are you making a new TestCase()? shouldn't you add the test that you found?

Comment: And what would a `Test` class be? What class should I extend?

Comment: @Peterdk The same you'll extend in JUnit 3 style test case: junit.framework.TestCase or some specification of it, which gives you additional features.

Comment: @Danail Nachev: Sorry, but this is all non-sense (not your fault). JUnit4 proudly replaced inheritance by annotations, so I don't have any `Test`, just plain old classes. So your solution doesn't work for me, unless I edit them all.

Comment: how to implement the findAllTestCasesRuntime() method?

Comment: @5YrsLaterDBA This depends on your specific case: you may use external files to determine the list of tests, you can scan classpaths for specifically annotated classes or something even crazier. The only requirement is that findAllTestCasesRuntime() returns the list of junit.framework.Test classes (or subclasses), which will be added to the suite.

Comment: I am using JUnit 4 and none of  my test classes are a subclass of Junit Test interface.

Comment: You can use ```junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter``` to construct a suitable object to represent your test classes.

Comment: But where is the method `findAllTestCasesRuntime()`?  Without that the listing is incomplete.

Comment: @KrishPrabakar you are free to implement it however you feel like. The answer just shows how two different patterns in JUnit 3 are mapped to JUnit 4 constructs.

Comment: In other words, there IS no "free" solution to do this, we have to build a list of test classes manually? Well that's rubbish...

Answer (score 35):

I've tried this using JUnit 4.8 and it works:

```
@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public class SomeTests
{
    public static TestSuite suite()
    {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test1.class));
        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test2.class));

        return suite;
     }
}
```

Comment: What do I do with this method? I want the suite be become a child of my parent suite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834908

Comment: I tried that but when I add `@BeforeClass` annotation it, the code inside `@BeforeClass` doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: What does `JUnit4TestAdapter` do?

Comment: @Arik `AllTests` runner does not favor `@BeforeClass`. Use [Suite sublcass](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1070568/902859)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what gatherTestClasses() does, but let's say it returns some tests when the OS is Linux and different tests when the OS is Windows. You can replicate that in JUnit 4.4 with [assumptions](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/ReleaseNotes4.4.html#assumptions):

```
@Test
public void onlyOnLinux() {
    assumeThat(getOS(), is(OperatingSystem.LINUX));
    // rest of test
}

@Test
public void onlyOnWindows() {
    assumeThat(getOS(), is(OperatingSystem.WINDOWS));
    // rest of test
}

@Test
public void anyOperatingSystem() {
    // just don't call assumeThat(..)
}
```

The implementation of `getOS()` and `OperatingSystem` being your custom code.

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. If you're using apache commons-lang, you can use "assumeTrue(SystemUtils.IS_OS_WINDOWS);"

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Complete example how to implement that. it combines of two testCase classes and one suite.

1. **ExampleInstrumentedTest:**

   ```
   import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

   import org.junit.Rule;
   import org.junit.Test;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

   @RunWith(JUnit4.class)
   public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {


       @Rule
       public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

       @Test
       public void checkInputs() throws Exception {

       }
   }
   ```
2. **ExampleInstrumentedTest2:**

   ```
   import android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule;

   import org.junit.Rule;
   import org.junit.Test;
   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

   @RunWith(JUnit4.class)
   public class ExampleInstrumentedTest2 {


       @Rule
       public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);

       @Test
       public void checkInputs() throws Exception {

       }
   }
   ```
3. **ExampleInstrumentedSuite:**

   ```
   import junit.framework.TestSuite;

   import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
   import org.junit.runners.AllTests;

   @RunWith(AllTests.class)
   public class ExampleInstrumentedSuite {

       public static TestSuite suite() {
           TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
           suite.addTest(new junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter(ExampleInstrumentedTest.class));
           suite.addTest(new junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter(ExampleInstrumentedTest2.class));
           return suite;
       }
   }
   ```

Note that you should use `@RunWith(JUnit4.class)` instead of default `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` in testCase Class

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyTestCase extends TestCase {
    @Override
    public void runTest() {
        // define assertion here  <===
        assertEquals("yes", "yes");
    }
}

@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public class DynamicTestSuite {
    public static TestSuite suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

        // dynamically create your test case here  <====
        suite.addTest(new MyTestCase());

        return suite;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @kissLife's answer, here's a something you can paste and run that creates multiple tests on the fly:

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public final class TestJunit4DynamicConstruction {
    public static TestSuite suite() {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
        suite.addTest(new CompareInts(1, 1));
        suite.addTest(new CompareInts(2, 2));
        suite.addTest(new CompareInts(2, 1)); // huh, for some reason, 2 != 1
        suite.addTest(new CompareInts(1, 1));
        return suite;
    }

    static public class CompareInts extends TestCase {
        private final int got;
        private final int expected;

        CompareInts(int got, int expected) {
            super(Integer.toString(got) + ":" + Integer.toString(expected));
            this.got = got;
            this.expected = expected;
        }
        @Override
        public void runTest() {
            assertEquals(got, expected);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll run these tests:

```
TestJunit4DynamicConstruction$CompareInts.1:1
TestJunit4DynamicConstruction$CompareInts.2:2
TestJunit4DynamicConstruction$CompareInts.2:1
TestJunit4DynamicConstruction$CompareInts.1:1
TestJunit4DynamicConstruction$CompareInts
```

and get this error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :2
Actual   :1


    ...
TestJunit4DynamicConstruction$CompareInts.runTest(TestJunit4DynamicConstruction.java:26)
   ...


Process finished with exit code 255
```