# JUnit - Listener for when ALL test classes have been executed?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, junit4

I've been searching for a while but I still can't find a way to do what I want.

I run my unit tests in Eclipse with the "Run as JUnit test" on the whole project.

I implemented a custom RunListener which record some test results information in a singleton (Just FYI, this is not meant to record only test results, I know we can export junit reports for that regard. This is meant to catch additional information which are in test methods custom annotations).

I'd like to persist the singleton information on disk once ALL test have been executed.
(The keyword being ALL :) )

I know I can override testRunFinished (This is what I do right now),
but this method is called everytime all tests of one single class are executed (So once by test class).

Is it because the Eclipse "Run as" consider each class as a Suite by default?

While it works, it is not really efficient to persist the singleton state thousands times.

Also, I'd like to give a proper name to the persisted file (Like the binary versions + date) but I can't right now since I don't know when ALL tests have been executed so each time the file is persisted it would create a new file (Date containing milliseconds) although the tests are not over (and the singleton data is thus incomplete)

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: I found a workaround. I could create a TestSuite and create an AfterClass, but this means I would need to enumerate thousands classes, which is cumbersome... I'll look for a dynamic way to add all test classes to the suite but I'd like a better idea !

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I created a TestSuite, with an @AfterClass static method to only persist once my singleton state.

This means I have to add all my test classes in the Suite.

Fortunately, thanks to JavaRocky, I dynamically included all my test classes with a custom annotation.

See answer here: [How do I Dynamically create a Test Suite in JUnit 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257080/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-test-suite-in-junit-4).

If someone has an easier way to accomplish a @AfterAllTestRuns ... let me know !