# Junit4: how to create test suite dynamically

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, junit3

I have huge set of JUnits in my projects. Out of which, I would like to execute certain set by looking up the classes from a property file.

Prior to JUnit 4:

```
public class TestSuite
{
    public static Test suite()
    {
       TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();
       Class [] array = readFromPropertyFile();

       for (Class tempClz : array)
       {
           suite.addTestSuite(tempClz);
       }

    }
}
```

However in Junit4, I'm forced to annotate the classes at compile time as follows:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
   Test1.class,
   Test2.class
})
    public class TestSuite
    {
    }
```

I cannot, switch back to Junit 3.x because, all the test classes are no more extending `TestCase` meaning Test1.class is not of type `Class<? extends TestCase>`

Is there a way to dynamically configure the testsuite in this case ?

Comment: Is JUnit4 is not compatible to the earlier approach, it should be.

Comment: as I said, `suite.addTestSuite(tempClz);` expects tempClz to be `Class<? extends TestCase>` where I get an error (compile time).

Comment: I had the same issue, see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/42423367/2267723

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [cpsuite](http://johanneslink.net/projects/cpsuite.jsp) project uses a custom annotation to determine the tests to run at runtime based on patterns.  This isn't what you want, but it is a good start.  You can take the source code for it and replace the "find tests" part with reading from your property file.

Note that the annotation/code is different for different versions of JUnit 4.X.  If you are still on JUnit 4.4 or below, you'll need the older one.