# How do I Dynamically create a Test Suite in JUnit 4 when the test files are not extending to TestCase?

Tags: java

I want to add testfiles to a testsuite at runtime and my test files are not extending to Testcase as i am using junit 4.11.

Below is the code:

```
@RunWith(org.junit.runners.AllTests.class)

class MasterTester extends TestCase{

public static TestSuite suite1() {

TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

        for(Class<? extends TestCase> klass : gatherTestClasses()) {
          suite.addTestSuite(klass);
        }

        return suite;
      }

private  static Class<?> gatherTestClasses()
{


    return AbcIT.class;//getting a compile time error
    }

}
```

I am getting a compile time error saying class of type cannot be added to class

Please suggest?

Comment: Why are you passing the instance of `Class<? extends TestCase>` to `suite.addTestSuite()` ? It does not take that type of input. Its just plain `Class`.

Comment: it doesnot. It takes instance of Class<? extends Testcase> only

Comment: Oops! I was referring to older version.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps have a look at @Andrejs answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257080/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-test-suite-in-junit-4) as he mentions dynamically adding JUnit 4 testcases to a testsuite:

```
@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public class SomeTests
{
    public static TestSuite suite()
    {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite();

        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test1.class));
        suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(Test2.class));

        return suite;
     }
}
```