# How can I run a (JUnit) TestSuite created by a factory method?

Tags: java, junit

I was looking for a verification test for custom implemented collections, and stumbled upon this: http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2012/09/google-guava-collection-test-suite/

I haven't used junit before (so I'm a total noob with junit). I added junit4 to my test project and... got stuck on how to actually *run* the test suite created by the Google Guava Collection Test Suite. I run annotated test from my test class just fine, but not the test suite from guava.

The junit docs say that suites are created by annotating a suite class with the Suite annotation, listing the cases they should include, but obviously I can't list a dynamically generated class that way. I would be happy to just create a simple test and run the entire suite as a single test, only... how do I get junit to run the suite instance?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257080/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-test-suite-in-junit-4 ? I think you should be able to follow those patterns to wrap up a call to the factory method to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11932146/733345).

Comment: @tuckermi You should post that as an answer (maybe with a summary/quote).

Comment: Sure. I will write up something now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a factory method that returns a `Test` object (let's call it `TestMaker.foo()`, then you can write something like the following to take the `Test` and add it to your own `TestSuite` class:

```
import junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.AllTests;

@RunWith(AllTests.class)
public class TestRunner {
    public static TestSuite suite() {
        TestSuite ts = new TestSuite();

        ts.addTest(TestMaker.foo());

        return ts;
    }
}
```

Now, when you run the `TestRunner` tests, it will also run the `Test` returned by `TestMaker.foo()` along with any other tests that might be defined directly in `TestRunner`.

For related discussion (for example, how to refer to a Test Class rather than pass a Test object), check out: [How do I Dynamically create a Test Suite in JUnit 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257080/how-do-i-dynamically-create-a-test-suite-in-junit-4)